# Fetch Row's until quantity has been met

Tags: php, mysql

I have a SQL Database and I wish to obtain records until the customer's quantity requested has been met. Here is what I mean. 
Request Table

```
Product     Quantity   Price
-----------------------
Apple          10.0      5.00
```

here is the SQL query to obtain matches:

```
SELECT c.FName,
       p.ProductName,
       s.Description, 
       s.Quantity, 
       s.Price 
FROM requests r
    INNER JOIN sellers s 
        ON r.ProductID = s.ProductID
   INNER JOIN products p 
        ON p.ProductID=s.ProductID 
   INNER JOIN customers c 
        ON c.ID=s.C_ID       
WHERE r.C_ID = 3 AND r.matchType='Price'
ORDER BY s.Price ASC
```

And here is the result:

```
     FName   |   ProductName    |     Description                 |  Quantity  |   Price
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------=
 compny1          Apple                    royal apples fm appleco.      5.0          5.00
    daz            Apple                     sweet apples                6.0          5.50
company2         Apple                       Apples yum                   8.0          9.00
```

I want to display the full requested 10KG quantity by selecting the rows and updating the database i.e. the output should be:

```
apples @5kg from compny1 = 5.00
apples @5kg from daz = 5.50
total = 10.50
```

the Database should then show 'Daz' quantity being 1.0 KG left. However, I keep getting suck in doing this. I have tried to do the following:

```
  while ($rows1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryQuantity2)){

        if($rows1['Quantity']==$quantityRequested){ //If the first row = 10KG output only this row.
echo $rows1['FName'];
echo $rows1['NameProduct'];
echo $rows1['Quantity'];
echo $rows1['Price'];
}else{
//stuck here check the next rows and see there is 6KG's .. We need 10KG Requested - 5KG from daz(row1) 
//                                                                            -Remaining amount left(i.e.5KG)
//hence, print the output specified above and UPDATE Database where quantity has been reduced by X amount.
}
```

Ok, So what the problem is. I need to 'Make up' the 10KG requested demand.

Now the 'Cheapest' way to do this is by sorting the available matches by Asc Price which I have.

No we can see the First row shows 'compny1' selling 5KG for £5.00... So, we need 10KG hence we display row 1.. 
Next, as we have not met the 10KG demand yet (still need another 5KG) we look at the second row. We see 'daz' is selling 6KG. but we only need 5more KG's to make the 10KG demand. 
Hence, what I wish to do is... UPDATE the table so that the first record is copied to another table and the second row is updated to 1.0kg remaining(6KG-5KG). And hence, display to the customer:
Your 10KG can be purchased by

```
compny1 5KG@5.00
daz 5KG@5.50
------ 
Total £10.50
```

So, that is my problem. I dont know how to keep checking the rows until the quantity requested is met. I guess I need some kind of 'counter' that keeps track of how much quantity has been added added 'So far' and then check how much more is needed from the next row.

Comment: So do you want to stop your returned results once you meet a certain criteria, in this case a quantity of 10?  How do you get 5.50 for the apples return by daz since 6 cost 5.50 -- should 5 cost 4.58?  Just trying to understand your issues.

Comment: @sgeddes Yes. Once the quantity has been met (10kg in this case) the demand has been met hence no more rows need to be displayed.  Yes sorry about the costing atm that is just sample and test data. After I will change it for price per KG and then sort the list.

Answer (score 0):

While there might be a simplified version of this, this should be pretty close:

```
Select FName, 
  IF(summedQty>10,Quantity-(summedQty-10),Quantity) Quantity,
  Price
From (
  Select 
    FName, 
    Quantity, 
    Price,
    @qtySum:=IF(@qtySum>10,10000,@qtySum+Quantity) summedQty
  From Results
    Join (Select @qtySum:=0) t
  Order By Price
  ) t
Where summedQty != 10000
```

I used 10000 as an arbitrary value I know I'll never hit -- just make sure it's higher than any potential value.  And anywhere I used 10, you'll need to substitute with the max value.

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ff3b/1)

If you don't want to use an arbitrary value as such, this appears to work just as well:

```
Select FName, 
  IF(summedQty>10,Quantity-(summedQty-10),Quantity) Quantity,
  Price
From (
  Select 
    FName, 
    Quantity, 
    Price,
    @qtySum:=@qtySum+Quantity summedQty
  From Results
    Join (Select @qtySum:=0) t
  Order By Price
  ) t
Where IF(summedQty>10,Quantity-(summedQty-10),Quantity) > 0
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ff3b/4)

As I said, I'm sure there are variations, but this should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. This may sound really dopy but I am using mySQL(PHP myAdmin) I have not seen this sort of syntax before using IF's in SQL queries. Can you use these sort of queries for php/sql And also the 10KG is just for this customer other customers will have different quantities requested.  What I ideally thought was using PHP to process the result and update the table. However, I don't know how to go about to do this:'(

Comment: @Jsmith -- You can definitely use IF statements in your sql statements from PHP -- valid SQL Syntax.  You'd need to replace the 10 with whatever value was specific for that customer.  I was trying to get you a MySQL solution vs a PHP solution.  And btw, I'm sure you noticed, I used a fake Results table -- replace that with your actual query.  Best regards!

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestion I will use it to help me solve my problem. I just thought maybe using PHP will be a bit easier for myself to understand as I have not really used this sort of SQL syntax before:)

Comment: @Jsmith -- np, hope it helped.  I don't know php well enough to offer a solution on that end.  Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks once again. If you do have time. I would be highly grateful if you could check out this link [link](http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/obtain-data-from-sql-db-until-condition-has-been-met-940908.html)
As I have explained here with more explanation of what I wish to achieve. 

Thanks:)